# Generating API from swagger model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I've taken the 'pets' example from swagger, and was wanting to use the scaffolding of Web API 2 to generate the controller.  On doing so, it tells me:

'There was an error running the selected code generator.  The property Pet.PhotoUrls could not be mapped, because it is of type List which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type.  Either explicity map this property, or ignore it.'

In the constructor of the generated 'Pet' model class we see this:

```
List<string> PhotoUrls = default(List<string>)
```

This model class came straight from the server code generator of the swagger editor, so I would have thought it would be ready for this type of process.  What's the recommended approach here?  Just avoid such parameters in your own API's?

Comment: `List<T>` is a NET thing (which internally uses an array), if you're exposing an API then it is best to use types that comply with the CLS, such as arrays. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3(v=vs.100).aspx Also, `default(List<string>)` == `null`, the default value of a List<T> (and other reference types) is null.

Comment: I agree, but why wouldn't the swagger devs (who it says apply best practice in the generators) use an array or other suitable construct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question, but overall it may not be displaying it as an array because it's not, and falsely reporting information back to consumers of that API will lead to frustration or unexpected behavior. Change your type to `string[]` and see if that works. Swagger should detect arrays fine because arrays are CLS compliant, whereas a List is a .NET thing while C++ uses something such as a Vector